# Tab order starting from url

Tags: jquery, html, browser

Is it possible to somehow make it so that when you are in the url bar of your browser and you press TAB you go to the first inputfield on your page and not your bookmarks or something else?

Using focus() could somehow be a workaround but it's not what I am looking for.

So focus is in URL bar, user presses TAB, focus goes to the first input field :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible with jQuery as you are trying to change the "tab index" of your browser software. This is outside the contraints of jQuery. Ie. Its outside of the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model).

If there is a way of changing it, I doubt it is possible to do this cross-browser, and would probably be only possible for your particular instance of your browser software.

Comment: I thought it was something like that, but just want to be sure :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that by setting [`tabindex` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex), like you set any other attributes. If you wish to do that in scripting, and not directly in HTML, you just use the `attr()` method.

The details depend on the page structure and desired behavior, and you need to understand how the `tabindex` attributes specify the tabbing order. Consider a very simple case, where you have just a `<div class=nav>` containing navigational links and another part of the page containing `input` fields. Suppose you want the fields to be tabbed first, and only after them the navigation links. You can then write:

```
$('input').attr('tabindex', 1);
$('.nav a').attr('tabindex', 10000);
```

It’s that simple in a simple case, since elements sharing the same `tabindex` value are tabbed in the order in which they appear in HTML source.

Comment: No what I want is that my input field is being used before bookmarks or other stuff. I have the focus in my URL bar and when I press on TAB I go to my bookmarks. I want to go to my input field then. I don't think it's possible but want to make sure :)